# Tunnel Connection Failed error when logging into artifactory docker registry

Tags: ssl, nginx, docker, artifactory

We have created a private docker registry in artifactory. 
Our artifactory is a standalone installation and have Nginx as a webserver.
SSL certificates are trusted and works fine.

on docker client, I have copied the ca.crt to /etc/docker/certs.d/:5001/
while am trying to login or push images from my docker client i see below error.

[root@cds-dev-test ~]# docker login artifactory.host:5001
Username: raj
Password:
Email: raj@gmail.com
Error response from daemon: invalid registry endpoint

https://artifactory.host:5001/v0/: unable to ping registry endpoint 
v2 ping attempt failed with error: Get https://artifactory.host:5001/v2/: Tunnel Connection Failed
 v1 ping attempt failed with error: Get artifactory.host:5001/v1/_ping: Tunnel Connection Failed. If this private registry supports only HTTP or HTTPS with an unknown CA certificate, please add `--insecure-registry artifactory.host:5001` to the daemon's arguments. In the case of HTTPS, if you have access to the registry's CA certificate, no need for the flag; simply place the CA certificate at /etc/docker/certs.d/artifactory.host:5001/ca.crt

my docker version is 1.9.1 and artifactory versioin 4.4.3.

It works when i use --insecure-registry option but not the secure way. We have all trusted certs in place, still see the error.

I have tried using proxy settings on docker client and also without proxy... always the same error.

Any help guys?

Comment: I see you wrote you put the certificate in `/etc/docker/certs.d/:5001/` when it should be `/etc/docker/certs.d/artifactory.host:5001/ca.crt` like the error states... also, did you [restart](https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/) the docker service / daemon after copying the certificate?

Comment: yes i did, my bad i copied it wrong. i have put the certificate here /etc/docker/certs.d/artifactory.host:5001/ca.crt.

yes i have restarted the docker services. still it doesnt work.

Comment: when i try url in browser https://artifactory.host:5001/v2/  i get
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 401,
    "message" : "Unauthorized"
  } ]
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

I have proxy settings under my docker deamon. I have added No_Proxy and it works fine.

FYI....
so people if you are using trusted CA cert, and your network is behind proxy, make sure your docker services file doesnt have proxy settings, if it does add No-proxy=artifactory.host.

/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf

Thanks